# Safenet Authentication Client Tools error when Reboot or restart the eTSrv- and pcscd-services

Tags: java, android, linux

Command: sudo /etc/init.d/eTSrv start

- Starting eTSrv daemon eTSrv                                                  /usr/bin/eTSrv:

error while loading shared libraries: libeToken.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure that you do have libeToken.so ([should be](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+package/libetoken) in `libtoken` package).

If you don't have this then install it; otherwise, run `sudo ldconfig` to update your library locations.

Answer (score -1):

Mister, first find the library

```
$ sudo find / -name libeToken.so.8
```

Then make a symbolic link

```
$ sudo ln -s /serch/result/libeToken.so.8 /usr/lib/libeToken.so.8
```

"/serch/result/" directory result of find command

Comment: This is very dangerous! Let the packages configure themselves. If a library can't be found then use `ldconfig`